# How to get all files in a subdirectory of isostorage

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I want to list all files in a subdirectory on istostorage

```
Public Function GetAllFilesInDirectory(ByVal DirectoryName As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim isoStore As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

        Dim L As New List(Of String)
        For Each di As String In isoStore.GetDirectoryNames
            If di = DirectoryName Or di & "/" = DirectoryName Then

                For Each fi As String In isoStore.GetFileNames'<-- fails because not the subdirectory is listed
                    If fi.StartsWith(DirectoryName) Then L.Add(fi)
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Return L
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB.NET developer, so I used a converter to convert from my [old C# version](http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/view-your-apps-isolated-storage-structure/). See if this helps read all directories:

```
Public Shared Sub GetIsolatedStorageView(pattern As String, storeFile As IsolatedStorageFile)   

    Dim root As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pattern)

    If root <> "" Then
        root += "/"
    End If

    Dim directories As String() = storeFile.GetDirectoryNames(pattern)
    'if the root directory has no FOLDERS, then the GetFiles() method won't be called.
    'the line below calls the GetFiles() method in this event so files are displayed
    'even if there are no folders
    If directories.Length = 0 Then
        GetFiles(root, "*", storeFile)
    End If


    For i As Integer = 0 To directories.Length - 1
        Dim dir As String = directories(i) + "/"



        'Write to output window
        Debug.WriteLine(root + directories(i))


        'Get all the files from this directory
        GetFiles(root + directories(i), pattern, storeFile)

        'Continue to get the next directory  
             GetIsolatedStorageView(root + dir + "*", storeFile)
    Next


End Sub

Private Shared Sub GetFiles(dir As String, pattern As String, storeFile As IsolatedStorageFile)

    Dim fileString As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pattern)

    Dim files As String() = storeFile.GetFileNames(pattern)    


    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To storeFile.GetFileNames(dir + "/" + fileString).Length - 1    
            'Files are prefixed with "--" 
            Debug.WriteLine("--" + dir + "/" + storeFile.GetFileNames(dir + "/" + fileString)(i))
        Next

    Catch ise As IsolatedStorageException
        Debug.WriteLine("An IsolatedStorageException exception has occurred: " + ise.InnerException)

    Catch e As Exception

        Debug.WriteLine("An exception has occurred: " + e.InnerException)
    End Try


End Sub
```

If you want it for development purposes, you could use the [wp7explorer tool](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: Hi keyboardP. First, let me say thank you for your quick response. You say I need to use the pattern of `GetFileName()` to get subdirectory file. `Dim files As String() = storeFile.GetFileNames(pattern) `. First, I wrote the file ("database/test.txt") then I've check it `.Exists = True` and now I still can not list the file by using the GetFileNames methode (GetFileNames("datbase/"). WP7 File Explorer shows the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi keyboardP. Thanks again. I got the trick with the `*` because of your example. Thanks a lot... you made my day :-)

Comment: You're welcome :) The `*` is wildcard so it will match everything.